# Word repetition when a word is part of more words

Tags: grammar, repetition

> The output consists of the category bar and the navigation bar.

How do I prevent the word repetition of *bar* in the English language?
Is it the following?

> The output consists of the category and the navigation bar.

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is fine because you're introducing two items that are siblings. The "bar" is an important part of both items. An example would be like

"Here is a Phillips screwdriver and here is a Robertson screwdriver."

Answer (score 0):

I would pluralize the word "bar" (since there are two of them) and say:

> The output consists of the category and navigation bars.

Your version could be interpreted to mean that the output consists of a navigation bar and a category (not a category bar).

Comment: Or indeed a bar that covers both navigation and categories (if the article is removed and _bar_ kept in the singular).